# Why the 3rd parameter of __libc_start_main has name ubp_av and not argv?

Tags: c, libc

In the following prototype   :

```
int __libc_start_main( int (*main) (int, char * *, char * *),
    int argc, 
    char **ubp_av, 
    void (*init) (void),
    void (*fini) (void),
    void (*rtld_fini) (void),
    void (* stack_end) );
```

Why does `ubp_av` appear and not `argv`?
And what does `ubp_av` mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`libc` is a library which is deeply tied to the specific OS, processor, and often compiler used. So, it's not uncommon to see some fairly arcane stuff in the `libc` sources.

In this case, `ubp_av` is an *unbounded* pointer to `argv`. GCC provides the (not-well-documented) `__bounded` and `__unbounded` type annotations which control certain bounds-checking operations on the pointers. Presumably because `argv` is supplied by the OS, it is considered unbounded (i.e. could point to memory of essentially any length), and presumably due to `libc` coding standards it is required to be marked as such.

Here's a slightly different function signature from a particular version of the GNU C Library:

```
int
/* GKM FIXME: GCC: this should get __BP_ prefix by virtue of the
   BPs in the arglist of startup_info.main and startup_info.init. */
  BP_SYM (__libc_start_main) (int argc, char *__unbounded *__unbounded ubp_av,
                  char *__unbounded *__unbounded ubp_ev,
                  ElfW (auxv_t) * __unbounded auxvec,
                  void (*rtld_fini) (void),
                  struct startup_info *__unbounded stinfo,
                  char *__unbounded *__unbounded stack_on_entry)
{
#if __BOUNDED_POINTERS__
  char **argv;
#else
# define argv ubp_av
#endif

...
```

from which you can clearly see that `ubp_av` means "unbounded pointer to argv".

Comment: Thee links helped me to better understand your answer; I add to help others:  [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_pointer),   [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/bp/main.html),  [link](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/glibc-linux/2000-q2/msg00145.html)   That gcc project seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** [nneonneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24146722/827263) is better than mine.

`argv` is the second argument to `main`, and it's of type `char**`.

This function `__libc_start_main` has 7 parameters. The first is a pointer to a function that looks like it's meant to be compatible with `main` -- with an additional third argument that's probably the environment pointer. The declaration of this function pointer omits the names of the parameters of the pointed-to function. If those names had been include, the first line could have been:

```
int __libc_start_main( int (*main) (int argc, char **argv, char **envp),
```

followed by the other 6 parameter declarations.

Given the name, `__libc_start_main` is probably a function in the runtime library that's responsible for calling the `main` function of a user program.

The second argument is `int argc`, but that's distinct from the first argument to `main`.

Without more details (particularly which implementation of the C library this is from), all I can say about `upb_av` is that it's the third parameter of `__libc_start_main`, and that it's of type `char**`. The `av` suffix indicates that it's some kind of argument vector, but I don't know what the `upb` prefix means. It may be related to `argv`, but it's a distinct thing.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of main() is envp and it's always passed on the stack to main(), even if not present in the declaration, that's even if we write: int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }

Comment: @user2431763: In what context? `envp` is a common extension, but the C standard doesn't mention it.

Comment: You are right, I tried with gcc 4.7.2 in Debian wheezy (32 bit)

Comment: @Keith Thompson In the C11dr §J.5.1 Environment arguments 'In a hosted environment, the main function receives a third argument, char *envp[], ...".  Of course, Appendix J of the Spec is _informative_.  So `envp` as a third augment of `main()` is not the the spec part of the C spec.